# Receive byte[] and display it on ImageView android

Tags: java, android, sockets, imageview

Im doing an Server/Client implementation and i need to send from Server a byte[] (image already converted) to the client.

I have the server sending, and the client receiving the byte[], but i cant paint it on my imageView.

I have the following code for client

class ViewerThread extends AsyncTask Void, Void, Void>...

```
public void startSharing(ImageView img_viewer) {

try {
            ObjectInputStream in_client = null;
            try {

                byte[] byteArray;
                Bitmap bmp;

                while (true) {
                    in_client = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    Log.e(TAG_THREAD, "Waitting for new image...");
                    //Log.e(TAG_THREAD, "Viewer: -> trying to read.....");
                    //Read byte[] -> image to draw
                    byteArray = (byte[])in_client.readObject();
                    Log.e(TAG_THREAD, "Received! -> " + byteArray.toString() + " size: "+ byteArray.length);

                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
                    //-> draw
                    Log.e(TAG_THREAD, "drawing... -> " + byteArray.toString() + " size: "+ byteArray.length);

                    img_viewer.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                    img_viewer.refreshDrawableState();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Server - Error transfering bitmaps: "
                        + e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                in_client.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Looking for LogCat i have:

```
Waitting for new image...
Received! -> [B@4052b700 size: 293438
drawing... -> [B@4052b700 size: 293438
```

But it doesnt move on from here... Only if i stop the server, the image appears in my ImageView object.

The Activity:

```
img_viewer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_viewer);

ViewerThread vt = new ViewerThread(getString(R.string.server_address), 
            getString(R.string.port_number));

vt.execute();

Log.e("tag", "Viewer is connected to server!");

vt.startSharing(img_viewer);
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: while (true) never completes?

Comment: this is a dummy client that keeps waitting for server byte[] objects

Comment: Maybe, but you never leave the loop (as far as I can tell)...

Comment: @user1907954 - It's unrelated to your problem but you shouldn't need to call refreshDrawableState() on the ImageView after setting the image bitmap. Also, is this on the main thread or a background thread?

Comment: @Shiki I know it never leaves the cycle but im just testing.

Comment: @user1907954 even without refreshDrawableState() i dont have my image. This function is inside "class ViewerThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>", this is a method called "startSharing(imageView)", called after the exectue function

Comment: Learn how to use the debugger!  You would find this easily (at least the cause).

Comment: Use rather `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in_client);`

Comment: Why at all do you need ObjectInputStream? what kind of object do you pass to the output stream on the other side socket?

Comment: @TomaszGawel Server is passing byte[] using ObjectOutputStream, and client is receiving byte[] by ObjectInputStream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not clear from your code example but I think this code runs in the UI thread.

As long as your code is in the while loop the user interface can't refresh the picture. As soon as you stop the server you get an exception that you catch. This leaves the while loop and allows the UI to redraw itself. Therefor you can see then the image.

Comment: What would you recommend me to change? how could i update the imageView?

Comment: As soon as you have received the image you should end the while loop. Even better, but more complicated, would be that you have the socket communication in a background thread and pass the data then to the UI thread to show it.

Comment: I just tested my app doing one cycle (without while loop) and the image was transfered and loaded in my ImageView as i wanted! Now i need to change my code in a way that the client is always listening for new images. Could you give me an example how to do it in a simpler way? i dont know if i understood your concept.

Comment: As I'm not used to the android api I can't tell you what the recommended way is to create a background thread. Maybe someone else can bring some more light in it. Have a look in the adroid development documentation or ask a specific question for this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help @RolandBar! [New topic related with this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475985/android-thread-listenning-port-and-drawaing)

Answer (score 0):

user1907954

You can loop through the received bytes and pass that through to the interface through a Handler. I use this to listen for received bytes on a socket connection. Make sure that the socket connection is threaded and is in the background. Android is a single threaded and will crash if you ask it do too much at one time.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
final Runnable updateUI00 = new Runnable()
{
  public void run() 
  {
     textIn.append("LOAD:" + response + "\n");
  }
};
```

...

(In your socket connection):

```
while (running) 
{                   
    charsRead = in.readInt();

    if (charsRead != -1) 
    {
        response += in.substring(0, charsRead);
        handler.post(updateUI00);           
    }
}
```